Comic book series where a young woman heads to college in a small town, and finds that every woman in town has abnormally large busts
As I recall it, the premise was played a bit for titillation (pun mildly intended), but also for mild body horror and drama. The protagonist moves to a small town where one of the first things she notices is that all of the women have improbably large bustlines. She initially assumes it's some sort of a prank, but her roommates shows that theirs are real, and states that it's just part of the town, leading the protagonist to assume that it's some sort of a genetics thing in a small gene pool, or maybe something in the water. It creates a bit of coveting on her part, as she's much more modestly endowed. Of course, in short order, she wakes up with her own enlarged breasts. And, somewhat suspiciously, she adapts rapidly to it being completely normal.
Much of the intermediate plot is kind of hazy in my head, but I remember that she winds up meeting her roommate's sister, who has grown so much that she has to walk around the house in a harness attached to the ceiling, but still sees nothing wrong with it. The main character, despite being oddly OK with her transformation, continues to try to get down to the bottom of things, and eventually learns why things are the way they are.

 A witch had been burned at the stake long ago by the town founder, and she levied a curse of gigantomastia on the town. She also survived the encounter, and is one of the other college students, maybe the roommate, who's just enjoying the situation (I'm pretty sure that she was bisexual, and was noted to have multiple varying partners of both sexes at the college). Except that there's also another evil version of her out there who wants revenge in a more bloody way. I vaguely remember the ending involving a fair amount of fire in the room that they fight her in, and the two versions managing to merge together to be a more cohesive whole.

I could have sworn that I ran into it on TV Tropes, but there's no mention of it on the Breast Expansion page, nor have my other searches born much fruit.

I don't know the answer but I'm going to guess this comic was written by a man.

@AndresF. Yeah, I mean a witch curses a town so that all the women have big boobs. The men are all going "yippee!"

I guess TV Tropes has a page for just about everything

And... found it. Turns out, the entry had been removed from TV Tropes Breast Expansion page due to NSFW content (Google yanks ads revenue if entries get too spicy), but was in the history. And, weirdly enough, they kept the actual works page up, albeit with no links.
Welcome to Chastity, a webcomic hosted on the Bestoryclub website, written by Saburo X, and illustrated by Hernán Cabrera and Mariano Navarro.

Mei Lau is a college freshman who's about to attend Eureka University, a college in a small New England town called Chastity. Despite having never stepped foot in the town before, its name alone has Mei expecting an ordinary time there. Those expectations are immediately shattered when she meets her roommates, the sarcastic goth Gwen and the warm and sunny Rayya, and more specifically their gigantic breasts.
Mei is quick to pass it off as a joke, but it turns out it's not a joke, and those are their real breasts. What's more, Mei finds out it's not just them; every woman in the town has insanely huge breasts. Among the many busty women, Mei, being flat chested, certainly stands out, but not for long, because after a few days, her breasts start growing to huge proportions as well. Finding all this just insane, Mei resolves to find out what in the town is causing this phenomenon.

